disabling compiler extensions in codelite
I am currently following a tutorial on how to code c++ the only problem is that the tutorial is using code::blocks and vscode I was perfectly fine for most of it until they said that I should disable compiler extensions they showed me that I needed to flag -pedantic-errors in the code::blocks version but the main problem this causes is that Codelite does not do it that way.
so I tried to discover what "flagging it" means I found out that I do want it enabled but I don't know how since there is no enable button it seems that it is enabled but alas I could not find any way to test it also I use mingw please give me information on what you know I am sorry if this is an obvious question but I really don't know.

Have you looked around in the Build Settings? https://docs.codelite.org/settings/build_settings/ Looks like there may be places to add/change compiler options or switches.


Right click on the porject you wwant to change and select "Settings..."
Check configuration at top (Release/Debug/...)
Select "Compiler" on left, then "C++ Compiler Options" on the right, "..." should appears at right, click on it.

List of checkbox appears, you might have
"Treat as errors the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++ [-pedantic-errors]"
tick on it.
If you don't have it, you might directly write option in "Enter other option" block.
